# BASH: Duplicate array and pass array by value

Tags: arrays, bash, pass-by-value

Suppose I have an array `foo` that looks like the below, notice the third element.

```
foo=("a" "b" "c c")
echo "${foo[2]}" # "c c"
echo "${#foo[@]}" # "3"
```

How might I create an exact duplicate of that array into a variable `bar`? 
And then if you want to pass that array (by value) into a function `baz`?

*Edit: Moved answer to answer.*

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `eval`? (Why do you think you need `eval` to accomplish that thing?)

Comment: `baz "${foo[@]}"` is the accepted and conventional way to pass an array by value, which makes your values accessible as `"$@"` inside the function. What you're _actually_ doing is not passing by value at all, but passing the name -- which is to say, passing by reference.

Comment: ...also, particularly for Bash 4.3 or newer, there are much better and safer ways to do pass-by-reference with no `eval` involved.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If I understand `baz "${foo[@]}"` correctly, it means no other arguments can be passed to the function?

Comment: correct, unless you get creative. For instance, you can pass the array _length_ before the array's _values_, and pop only that many items off the argv.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sounds like a lot boiler plate code to stick into each function you intended to use arrays in.

Comment: If you're repeatedly needing to pass more than one array into a shell function, you're typically doing something very, very unidiomatic, and your time would be better spent learning to get what you want done in a matter conformant with local best practices and idiom. Also, if you have a version of the shell with namevars, you can put that "boilerplate" into a function, and just call it.

Comment: (Of course, idiom evolves with the language; once releases with namevars are widely deployed, I expect the concept of what is and isn't widespread practice to change).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an array by *reference* (which is what your code actually does), bash 4.3 allows this to be done with namevars:

```
foo=( hello "cruel world" )

print_contents() {
  local -n array=$1
  printf '%q\n' "${array[@]}"
}

print_contents foo
```

If you want to pass by *value*, even easier (and functional even with ancient releases):

```
foo=( hello "cruel world" )

print_contents() {
  printf '%q\n' "$@"
}

print_contents "${foo[@]}"
```

If you want to pass multiple arrays by value, by contrast:

```
foo=( hello "cruel world" )
bar=( more "stuff here" )

print_arrays() {
  while (( $# )); do
    printf '%s\n' "Started a new array:"
    local -a contents=()
    local array_len
    array_len=$1; shift
    for ((n=0; n<array_len; n++)); do
      contents+=( "$1" ); shift
    done
    printf '  %q\n' "${contents[@]}"
  done
}

print_arrays "${#foo[@]}" "${foo[@]}" \
             "${#bar[@]}" "${bar[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding my answer as I was writing the question. Here's the train of thought.

Several attempts below

```
bar=foo           # String "foo"
bar=$foo          # First element of array foo "a"

bar=${foo[@]}
echo "${#bar[@]}" # "1"
echo "${bar[0]}"   # "a b c c"

bar=(${foo[@]})
echo "${#bar[@]}" # "4"
echo "${bar[2]}"   # "c"
echo "${bar[3]}"   # "c"

bar=("${foo[@]}")
echo "${#bar[@]}" # "3"
echo "${bar[2]}"   # "c c"




baz () {
  eval "bar=(\"\${$1[@]}\")"

  for item in "${bar[@]}"
  do
    echo "$item"
  done

  # a
  # b
  # c c
}
```

Comment: FYI -- your `baz` isn't declaring `bar` local, so it's actually modifying the **global** variable `bar`, rather than scoping that to your function.

Comment: ...also, I'm unclear on how this is "by value" -- the `$1` you pass in is the name of the variable -- a reference -- not its values.

Answer (score 0):

```
function baz {
  set $1[@]
  printf '%s\n' "${!1}"
}
foo=(a b 'c c')
bar=("${foo[@]}")
baz bar
```